# How to deal with seamless textures, tiles, and tesselation

Tags: armory, seams

I am facing an issue with patches of grounds and several meshes.
The fact is I have to split the ground into several patches and use LOD (which is not the issue).
A huge mesh cannot be detailed, and several meshes react badly to tesselation enven with a (I guess perfectly) seamless textures.

[image]

My only solution here is to scale all patches locally a little bit.

Comment: Sounds like job for UDIM Textures, but i'm not sure what your final goal is

Comment: thanks i'll chech it out.

Comment: I come up with a long list of textures and what seems to be a lack of dram (crashes).
Do you know if it's possible to use the same texture for all tiles ? I mean only one picture per udmi texture.

Comment: No, it's a texture per tile, eve if the texture is the same

Comment: Ok thank you for specifying.
Can be real costly with a lot of lod meshes i can't with my 8gb computer.